# Number guessing what the user has in mind C

Tags: c

I'm trying to create a program where the program guesses what kind of number the user has in mind. First it will ask the user for a minimum and maximum number, for example 1 and 10(the number I have in mind should be between 1 and 10 then).
Lets say I have the number 4 in mind and the program will output a number. I can type in L for low, H for high or G for good.
If I type in L, the program should generate a number lower than the guessed number, for H it should guess an higher number. If I input G, the program should stop and print out how many times it guessed.
I have added my code below, what am I missing?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int minNumber;
    int maxNumber;

    int counter;

    printf("Give min and max: ");
    scanf("%d %d", &minNumber, &maxNumber);

    //printf("%d %d", minNumber, maxNumber);

    int num_between_x_and_y = (rand() % (maxNumber - minNumber)) + minNumber;

    char input[100];
    do {
        printf("is it %d? ", num_between_x_and_y);
        scanf("%s", input);
        if (input == 'L') {
            counter++;
        }
        if (input == 'H') {
            counter++;
        }
    } while (input != 'G');

    printf("I guessed it in %d times!", counter);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `if (input == 'L') {` --> `if (strcmp(input, "L")) {`

Comment: this is a classic question from school homework.

Comment: You're missing to generate a lower or higher random number.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg How do I generate a lower or higher number, everytime the user enters L or H?

Comment: You already know how to generate a random number in a specific range. Just change the range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not see any "counter" variable initialization

```
int counter = 1;
```

I do not see the new random number regeneration in the cycle, it should be something like:

```
 do {
        printf("is it %d? ", num_between_x_and_y);
        scanf("%s", input);
        if (input[0] == 'L') {
            counter++;
            maxNumber = num_between_x_and_y;

        }
        if (input[0] == 'H') {
            counter++;
            minNumber = num_between_x_and_y;
        }
        num_between_x_and_y = (rand() % (maxNumber - minNumber)) + minNumber;
    } while (input[0] != 'G');
```

Comment: This should be a comment, oh nevermind... didnt see your rep..., they should cange that

Comment: @Cristiano Why should the counter be set to 1 instead of 0?

Comment: @Teuntje Because you don't update the count on a correct guess. If the computer guesses correct on the first try you want it to print  `1` guesses, right?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `==` to compare strings (which are multiple bytes).

Either do `if (input[0] == 'L')` to just compare the first letter the user entered to a literal value, or `if (strcmp(input,"L") == 0)` to compare everything the user entered to the 1 character string literal (to use `strcmp` you will need to add `#include <string.h>`

Also your code is missing other things, like counter should be set to presumably set to zero before you use it. I assume you haven't finished your code yet because you can't get the user input part to work.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, how do i generate a lower or higher number, everytime the user enters L or H?

Comment: @Teuntje Use the last guess as upper or lower limit of your next guess. You need to be wary of "off by on" errors. You currently have an "off by one" error for the upper limit of the first guess.

Comment: We can help with syntax, logic is something you need to think carefully about. What do you do in your head if you were trying to solve this? What numbers would you keep track of (variables) and what math would you do on them (operations) and what choices would you make based on the values (conditional statements).